# Permission denied with ./configure

Tags: software-installation, permissions

I am trying to install Open MPI. I downloaded the archive and extracted the folder to `/home/`. I cded there and entered `./configure --prefix="/opt/openmpi"` and got this error:

```
./configure: line 4840: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 4850: config.log: Permission denied
```

I tried the following:

- `ls -l configure` which gives `-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root ... configure`
- `df -h .`. I'm on `/dev/sda6`
- `grep '\s/home/\s.*noexec' /proc/mounts` yields no results
- Prepend the command with `sh`

I try to avoid using `sudo` to install this. What can I do?

Comment: I think you do not have the rights to write to /home/ as non root user and if configure is root:root maybe that the directory have the same rights. So you have to chown all the directory or run configure as root...

Comment: IMHO it would be better to extract it to **your** actual `$HOME` i.e. `/home/username/`

Comment: @steeldriver I tried that as well. The location in `/home` is just the last place I tried before asking.

Comment: How are you extracting it into your $HOME? If you're using `sudo` ... **don't**

Comment: @steeldriver I only used `sudo` for the `chown` command. I copied the directory via GUI.

Comment: @DavidFoerster How is this question from 2015 a duplicate of a question posted in 2017?

Comment: @kleinfreund: Age is irrelevant here. There are multiple questions with the same underlying issue and answers suggesting the same solution(s). The decision which one should be the duplicate depends on which one has the more generally useful question and answer(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Lillox I needed to `chwon` the directory (e.g. `/home/openmpi-1.10.1`).

```
sudo chown -R user: .
```

(After the `:` the user-group is left out so this command uses the default user group.)

After that I continued installation with these commands:

```
./configure --prefix="/opt/openmpi"
make all install
```